# jQuery validation rule not working for nested html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a question about the validate method in jQuery and adding a rule to it, so say I have:

```
  $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
  zip: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 5,
    }
  }
});
```

now my form layout looks like this:

```
<body>
<div>
<form id="myform">
<label>
   <span>label</span>
   <input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" class="required" size="50">
</label>

<label>
         //some stuff here
</label>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Question is why is the validation not performed in zip? When I just have an input of text inside a body and nothing else it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

I just reviewed the site you linked and the jquery validate & delegate plugins are throwing 403's on your site (http://adityaherlambang.com/) . Update the url reference to those scripts and you should be good to go.

validate: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js

**Original:**

Looks like your validate js is a little off. Try using:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   rules: {
    zip: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 4
    }
  }
});
```

Related fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gp4vB/

Comment: I updated this fiddle to include the full form on your site: http://jsfiddle.net/gp4vB/2/

If, it is still not working, are you receiving errors within chromes / firebugs developer console?

Comment: if you visit the link above, does it actually validate?

Comment: Yes, the two fiddles I posted validate, your site is not validating as the jquery plugins you referenced appear to be throwing 403's. Update the url reference, remove the rogue "field: requied" block in your validate script, and you should be good to go.

Comment: where else should I update the reference if I have a 403? mine works in chrome but doesn't work in firefox and ie

Comment: I'm assuming that your chrome browse has the validate plugin cached which is why it is working. Your site is using this url: http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js

for the validate js file which is a dead url. Use the url I included in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You did not close the Zip input tag. It should look like below:

```
<input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" class="required" size="50" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't put `input` inside of `label`. It should be organized like:

```
<label for="cname">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" />
```

And close your `input` tag

```
<input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" class="required" size="50" />

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
                zip: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 4
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: why can't you put input inside of label?

Comment: yes, sorry, you are right. Just checked [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label)